# How archive like this CollectionView stacked Cell for Overlapping Cell Like Wallet

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want exactly when tap particular cell it will show expand

[image]

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.minimumLineSpacing = -UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2.08
```

i want expand cell?

Friends any suggestion and needs helpful for us
Thanks

Comment: Don't know anyone??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried it's working fine, thanks to everyone

```
class CardLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    var cachedAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    var nextIndexPath: Int?
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        var size = super.collectionViewContentSize
        let collection = collectionView!
        size.width = collection.bounds.size.width
        if let _ = FlowLayoutAttributes.shared.cellIndex{
            size.height = contentHeight+UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2+38
        }else{
            size.height = contentHeight
        }
        print("Contend",contentHeight)
        return size
    }
    
    
    func reloadData(){
        self.cachedAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    }
    
    override func prepare() {
        cachedAttributes.removeAll()
        guard let numberOfItems = collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) else {
            return
        }
        for index in 0..<numberOfItems {
            let layout = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))
            layout.frame = frameFor(index: index)
            
            if let indexExpand = FlowLayoutAttributes.shared.cellIndex, indexExpand ==  index {
                self.nextIndexPath = index+1
                contentHeight = CGFloat(CGFloat(numberOfItems)*getCardSize())+UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2+38*2
            }else{
                contentHeight = CGFloat(CGFloat(numberOfItems)*getCardSize())+UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2+38
            }
            layout.zIndex = index
            layout.isHidden = false
            
            cachedAttributes.append(layout)
        }
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        
        var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        
        for attributes in cachedAttributes {
            if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                layoutAttributes.append(cachedAttributes[attributes.indexPath.item])
            }
            
        }
        return layoutAttributes
    }
    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cachedAttributes[indexPath.item]
    }
    func frameFor(index: Int) -> CGRect {
        var frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(8), y:0), size: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - CGFloat(8 + 8), height: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2+38)))
        var frameOrigin = frame.origin
        if let indexExpand = FlowLayoutAttributes.shared.cellIndex{
            if index > 0 {
                if indexExpand < index {
                    let spacesHeight = CGFloat((getCardSize() * CGFloat(index)))+UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2+38-getCardSize()/2
                    frameOrigin.y = spacesHeight
                }else{
                    frameOrigin.y = CGFloat((getCardSize() * CGFloat(index)))
                }
            }
        }else{
            if index > 0 {
                frameOrigin.y = CGFloat((getCardSize() * CGFloat(index)))
            }
        }
        frame.origin = frameOrigin
        return frame
    }
    func getCardSize()-> CGFloat{
        if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
            case 1136:
                print("iPhone 5 or 5S or 5C")
                return  45.25
            case 1334:
                print("iPhone 6/6S/7/8")
                return  45.25
            case 1920, 2208:
                print("iPhone 6+/6S+/7+/8+")
                return  46
            case 2436:
                print("iPhone X/XS/11 Pro")
                return  45.25
            case 2688:
                print("iPhone XS Max/11 Pro Max")
                return  46
            case 1792:
                print("iPhone XR/ 11 ")
                return  46
            case 2532:
                print("iPhone 12/ iPhone 12 Pro")
                return  45.50
            case 2778:
                print("iPhone 12 Pro Max")
                return  46.2
            default:
                return  46.2
            }
        }else{
            return CGFloat(46.2)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually we use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, once the item's size and spacing is given, the item's frame is settled.

***To do***

> CollectionView stacked Cell for Overlapping Cell Like Wallet

You need to give the frame you want for every item in `UICollectionView`.

Finishing it by customizing `UICollectionViewLayout`, and use your own `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass.

The final effect is as the following image

[image: 11]

#### The basic thing:

To do custom layout is easy:

- `override public func prepare()` ,

to calculate the frames for every item,

And put the frame for item in its container , your custom `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`

- `override public func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?` ,

> Retrieves layout information for an item at the specified index path with a corresponding cell.

to assign your prepared custom `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` for item layout

- `override public func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?` ,

> Retrieves the layout attributes for all of the cells and views in the specified rectangle.

There is no supplementary views, and decoration views in this situation, just to handle items.

to assign your prepared custom `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` for `UICollectionView` layout

#### Key Point:

You have two kinds of layout state.

- the initial state, and the unselected state is the same, when no card is selected.

[image: 222]

The front card are partly hidden, and the last card is full shown.

The custom `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`, with `isExpand` to record if there is cell selected.

`isExpand` is used for an cell added `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

```
class CardLayoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    var isExpand = false

    override func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        let attribute = super.copy(with: zone) as! CardLayoutAttributes
        attribute.isExpand = isExpand
        return attribute
    }
}
```

The frame calculation of state unselected is easy.

Set the frame of the first item,

then the second ...

`y: titleHeight * CGFloat(index)` , all OK

```
 fileprivate func setNoSelect(attribute:CardLayoutAttributes) {
        guard let collection = collectionView else {
            return
        }
        let noneIdx = Int(collection.contentOffset.y/titleHeight)
        if noneIdx < 0 {
            return
        }
        attribute.isExpand = false
        let index = attribute.zIndex
        var currentFrame = CGRect(x: collection.frame.origin.x, y: titleHeight * CGFloat(index), width: cellSize.width, height: cellSize.height)
        if index == noneIdx{
            attribute.frame = CGRect(x: currentFrame.origin.x, y: collection.contentOffset.y, width: cellSize.width, height: cellSize.height)
        }
        else if index <= noneIdx, currentFrame.maxY > collection.contentOffset.y{
            currentFrame.origin.y -= (currentFrame.maxY - collection.contentOffset.y )
            attribute.frame = currentFrame
        }
        else {
            attribute.frame = currentFrame
        }
    }
```

- the selected state, to select an item, the item is expanded , others will make room for it.

The logic is to put the selected item in the middle, the `y` position matters, `collection.contentOffset.y + offsetSelected,`

The center item's frame is known , then calculate the two sides.

One side is items from `(selectedIdx-1)` to 0, calculate the frame of item.

The Other side is items from `(selectedIdx+1)` to the final index , also calculate item's frame.

```
    fileprivate func calculate(for attributes: [CardLayoutAttributes],  choose selectedIP: IndexPath) -> [CGRect]{
        
        guard let collection = collectionView else {
            return []
        }
        let noneIdx = Int(collection.contentOffset.y / titleHeight)
        if noneIdx < 0 {
            return []
        }
        let x = collection.frame.origin.x
        
        var selectedIdx = 0
        for attr in attributes{
            if attr.indexPath == selectedIP{
                break
            }
            selectedIdx += 1
        }
        
        var frames = [CGRect](repeating: .zero, count: attributes.count)
        
        // Edit here
        let offsetSelected: CGFloat = 100
        let marginBottomSelected: CGFloat = 10
        frames[selectedIdx] = CGRect(x: x, y: collection.contentOffset.y + offsetSelected, width: cellSize.width, height: cellSize.height)
        if selectedIdx > 0{
            for i in 0...(selectedIdx-1){
                frames[selectedIdx - i - 1] = CGRect(x: x, y: frames[selectedIdx].origin.y - titleHeight * CGFloat(i + 1), width: cellSize.width, height: cellSize.height)
            }
        }
        if selectedIdx < (attributes.count - 1){
            for i in (selectedIdx + 1)...(attributes.count - 1){
                frames[i] = CGRect(x: x, y: frames[selectedIdx].origin.y + marginBottomSelected + titleHeight * CGFloat(i - selectedIdx - 1) + cellSize.height, width: cellSize.width, height: cellSize.height)
            }
        }
        
        
        return frames
        
    }
```

[image: 9999]

- When there is a item selected, you should refresh the custom layout.

To call `invalidateLayout()`,

> Invalidates the current layout and triggers a layout update.

```
    fileprivate var _selectPath: IndexPath? {
        didSet {
            self.collectionView!.isScrollEnabled = (_selectPath == nil)
        }
    }
    
    
    
    public var selectPath: IndexPath? {
        set {
            _selectPath = (_selectPath == newValue) ? nil : newValue
            self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
                self.invalidateLayout()
            }, completion: nil)
        } get {
            return _selectPath
        }
    }
```

#### one more thing, [the sample demo in github](https://github.com/coyingcat/CardCollection)

Comment: thank you for your great demo it looks awesome, but I need this functionality can you solve this issue? 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67087648/collectionview-flowlayout-overlapping-when-scrolling-not-working)

Comment: What is your issue. The custom collection view layout is not hard.  The custom collection view layout with selected state is also not hard. Just follow my demo, and do a little change,

Comment: I tried your demo when I click the card it will be expand it's fine but scroll is not working, I try to solve but I couldn't

Comment: ```class CustomLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    
  override public var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
     CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth, height: contentHeight)
  }
}```

Comment: scroll thing depends on `contentHeight `. just try to modify its value

Comment: I mean this `class CustomLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {        override public var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {      CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth, height: 2500)   } }`

Comment: I tried dr, not working cards are not moving, show the scroll indicator only moving, and it's getting more reduce the battery percentage

Comment: can you fix that issue? I will pay for you

Comment: good deal. Please share your relevant code . I don't know your situation.

Comment: sure i added, please check.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the overlapping the layout, **minimumLineSpacing** negative number

> if click the card it should be expanded and scroll down and up card
> should not disclose anymoew like wallet

```
class OverlappedCustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()
        // This allows us to make intersection and overlapping
        // A negative number implies overlapping whereas positive implies space between the adjacent edges of two cells.
        minimumLineSpacing = -100
    }
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        for currentLayoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes in layoutAttributes! {
            // zIndex - Specifies the item’s position on the z-axis.
            // Unlike a layer's zPosition, changing zIndex allows us to change not only layer position,
            // but tapping/UI interaction logic too as it moves the whole item.
            currentLayoutAttributes.zIndex = currentLayoutAttributes.indexPath.row + 1
        }
        return layoutAttributes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following idea

The layout part:

```
var selectedIdx: Int?



override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        var originY: CGFloat = 0
        let defaultOffsetY: CGFloat = 80
        if let idx = selectedIdx{
            // expanded layout
            for i in 0..<cnt{
                 // frame the attribute
                 if i == idx + 1{
                       // to expand is to make room for the rest items
                       originY += 400
                 }
                 else{
                       originY += defaultOffsetY
                 }
            }
        }
        else{
            // default layout 
            for i in 0..<cnt{ 
                 // frame the attribute
                 originY += defaultOffsetY
            }
        }
        return layoutAttributes
    }
```

trigger the expand action

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // edit the state
        layout.selectedIdx = indexPath.item
        // trigger refreshing the collectionView's layout
        collectionView.reloadData()
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, how to expand the selected attribute from the array list?

Comment: to expand is to refresh the  collection layout. Not the scroll thing