# CollectionView FlowLayout overlapping when scrolling not working

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I hope you all working fine

Here I have created a collection view flow layouts some scenarios not working, please share your references.
here is the collection view

[image]

```
    import UIKit
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
        @IBOutlet weak var collection: UICollectionView!
        private let kCellHeight: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2+38
        private let kItemSpace: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2.08
        lazy var expand_click = false
        lazy var index_value = [String]()
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            collection.delegate = self
            collection.dataSource = self
            let layout = StickyCollectionViewFlowLayout2()
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = -kItemSpace
            collection.collectionViewLayout = layout
            collection.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 15
        }    
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
            print("Index",indexPath.row)
            return cell
        }
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width-40, height: kCellHeight)
        }
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if (15)-1 == indexPath.row {
                self.showAlert(alertText: "", alertMessage: "last Cell")
            }else{
                if index_value.contains("\(indexPath.row)") {
                    self.showAlert(alertText: "", alertMessage: "Redirect")
                    expand_click = true
                }else{
                    index_value.removeAll()
                    index_value.append("\(indexPath.row)")
                    expand_click = true
                    cellData = indexPath.row
                    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                    }, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

collection view cells

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
   
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        container.backgroundColor = .white
        container.layer.cornerRadius = 13
        container.layer.shadowRadius = 2
        container.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        container.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
        container.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.45).cgColor
    }    
}
```

> - When clicked cell it will be expanding the cell and moved to be under the other the cells
>   > * Expanded cell again click it will be redirected to another page forEx (I showed alert)
>   > * the last cell click it's should also redirect  These are all I have done my self if we have 15 cards it working fine more than 50 cards
>   > not smooth scrolling and we have a problem for contending size maybe I
>   > could not solve the issue

```
**Collection view FlowLayout**


class StickyCollectionViewFlowLayout2: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    
    var firstItemTransform: CGFloat?
    
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let items = NSArray (array: super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)!, copyItems: true)
        
        print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("Count-------->",items.count,"<--------Count")
        print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        
        
        var headerAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
        
        self.firstItemTransform = nil
        if cellData != nil {
            let min = cellData!
            print(min)
            var b = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?]()
            var a = false
            items.forEach({ (object) in
                let object  = object as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
                if min == object.indexPath.row {
                    a = true
                }else{
                    if a == true {
                        b.append(object)
                    }
                }
            })
            for attributes in b {
                if attributes?.representedElementKind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
                    headerAttributes = attributes
                }
                else {
                    self.atributeLayout(attributes!, headerAttributes: headerAttributes)
                }
            }
            cellData = nil
        }else{
            items.enumerateObjects(using: { (object, idex, stop) -> Void in
                let attributes = object as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
                
                if attributes.representedElementKind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
                    headerAttributes = attributes
                }
                else {
                    self.atributeLayoutReset(attributes, headerAttributes: headerAttributes)
                }
            })
        }
        return items as? [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
    }
    
    func atributeLayout(_ attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes, headerAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?){
        let minY = self.collectionView!.bounds.minY + self.collectionView!.contentInset.top
        var maxY = attributes.frame.origin.y+attributes.frame.height/2+80
        if let headerAttributes = headerAttributes {
            maxY -= headerAttributes.bounds.height
        }
        let finalY = max(minY, maxY)
        var origin = attributes.frame.origin
        let deltaY = (finalY - origin.y) / attributes.frame.height + 100
        
        if let itemTransform = self.firstItemTransform {
            let scale = 1 - deltaY * itemTransform
            attributes.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
        }
        origin.y = finalY
        attributes.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: attributes.frame.size)
        attributes.zIndex = attributes.indexPath.row
    }
    func atributeLayoutReset(_ attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes, headerAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?){
        cellIndex = nil
        if isExpandCell != true  {
            let minY = self.collectionView!.bounds.minY + self.collectionView!.contentInset.top
            var maxY = attributes.frame.origin.y
            if let headerAttributes = headerAttributes {
                maxY -= headerAttributes.bounds.height
            }
            let finalY = max(minY, maxY)
            var origin = attributes.frame.origin
            let deltaY = (finalY - origin.y) / attributes.frame.height + 100
            if let itemTransform = self.firstItemTransform {
                let scale = 1 - deltaY * itemTransform
                attributes.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
            }
            origin.y = finalY
            attributes.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: attributes.frame.size)
            attributes.zIndex = attributes.indexPath.row
            //            })
        }else{
            print(collectionView!.contentInset.top,collectionView!.bounds.minY)
            let minY = 0.0 + collectionView!.contentInset.top
            var maxY = attributes.frame.origin.y
            if let headerAttributes = headerAttributes {
                maxY -= headerAttributes.bounds.height
            }
            let finalY = max(minY, maxY)
            var origin = attributes.frame.origin
            let deltaY = (finalY - origin.y) / attributes.frame.height + 100
            if let itemTransform = firstItemTransform {
                let scale = 1 - deltaY * itemTransform
                attributes.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
            }
            origin.y = finalY
            attributes.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: attributes.frame.size)
            attributes.zIndex = attributes.indexPath.row
        }
    }
    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

if anyone experienced collection view please share me your references
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hello please try my code. I have tested on an iPhone simulator and it works great.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CardView: View {
    
    static let CARD_HEIGHT: CGFloat = 200
    static let CARD_WIDTH: CGFloat = 300
    static let TAB_HEIGHT: CGFloat = 30
    
    @State var selected: Int? = nil
    let cards: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                ForEach(0 ..< cards) { card_i in
                    Button {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.selected = self.selected == card_i ? nil : card_i
                        }
                        print("A card was tapped. Do something with card_i here")
                    } label: { self.card }
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    .frame(width: Self.CARD_WIDTH, height: Self.CARD_HEIGHT, alignment: .top)
                    .offset(x: .zero, y: CGFloat(card_i) * Self.TAB_HEIGHT + ((selected ?? cards + 1) < card_i ? Self.CARD_HEIGHT - Self.TAB_HEIGHT / 2 : 0))
                }
            }
            .frame(height: Self.CARD_HEIGHT + Self.TAB_HEIGHT * CGFloat(cards), alignment: .top)
            .padding()
        }
            
    }
    
    var card: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 17, style: .continuous)
            .fill(Color.gray)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 17, style: .continuous).stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 5))
    }
}
```

### Edit

Use it like this

```
let swiftUIview = CardView(cards: 10, onCardTapped: { card in 
    print("card number \(card) tapped")
})

let uiViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIview)
```

Gif removed because outdated.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it's awesome.  how can I implement in swift

Comment: Thanks! This is Swift code. To use in UIKit use the `UIHostingController` code I provided. Or refer to [this page](https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-in-uikit/). Also, see edited code.

Comment: how to remove top space and scroll is not working when having more than 100 cards

Comment: @ManikandanS I have changed the code and fixed all those problems. The scrolling works perfectly even with over 100 cards. And there is no more space at the top. Please copy the updated code and try it.

Comment: @ManikandanS of course! If this has solved your problem, perhaps you would consider marking as accepted and awarding the bounty?